# $T_0$ topological space with specific properties

Tags: general-topology

Is there an infinite $T_0$ topological space that has no finite open subset and no finite closed subset except empty set???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\in\Bbb R$ let $U_x=\{y\in\Bbb R:y<x\}$, and let

$$\tau=\{\varnothing,\Bbb R\}\cup\{U_x:x\in\Bbb R\}\;;$$

the space $\langle\Bbb R,\tau\rangle$ has the desired properties.